# CrytoJS AES decrypt returning a blank value - Typescript

Tags: typescript, cryptojs

I have the following Typescript code and have tried a few things but I am unable to get the decryption to work.  Would appreciate some insight.

Thanks in advance!

```ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UmCryptoService {
  constructor() {
  }
  encrypt<T>(key, value: T): string{
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    const i = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1583288699248111');
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(value), key, {iv: i}).toString();
    console.log('SS cipherText: ' + ciphertext);
    return ciphertext;
  }
  decrypt(key, value){
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    const i = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1583288699248111');
    const decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(value), key, {iv: i});
    console.log('SS utf8 decryptedData: ' + decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    return decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
}
```

In the console, I see:

```
LOG: 'SS cipherText: UbNlnYr0qd7ua0TcPTMIyxItPNvNscCfQYIP244Mt/5e7vPHZ1cFDWE9XgV7pA6a'
LOG: 'SS utf8 decryptedData: '
```

Here are a couple unit tests:

```ts
it('should encrypt string value', () => {
    const key = '1234567890987654321';
    const strValue = 'Hey check out this encryption!';
    const cipher = service.encrypt(key, strValue);
    console.log('SS: cipher str: ' + cipher);
    expect(cipher).toBeDefined();
    );
  });

fit('should decrypt cipher', fakeAsync (() => {
    const key = '1234567890987654321';
    const cipher = 'UbNlnYr0qd7ua0TcPTMIyxItPNvNscCfQYIP244Mt/5e7vPHZ1cFDWE9XgV7pA6a';
    const strValue = service.decrypt(key, cipher);
    tick(100000);
    console.log('SS: strValue: ' + strValue);
    expect(strValue).toBeDefined();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ciphertext must be passed to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` as `CipherParams` object or as Base64 encoded string (s. [*The Cipher Input*](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input)) and not as `WordArray` as in the actual code (assuming that `value` in `decrypt()` is the return value of `encrypt()`), i.e. a possible fix is:

```js
const decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {iv: i});
```

Complete code:

```js
function encrypt(key, value){
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    const i = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1583288699248111');
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(value), key, {iv: i}).toString();
    //console.log('SS cipherText: ' + ciphertext);
    document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = 'SS cipherText: ' + ciphertext;
    return ciphertext;
}

function decrypt(key, value){
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    const i = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1583288699248111');
    const decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {iv: i}); // Fix: pass Base64 encoded ciphertext
    //console.log('SS utf8 decryptedData: ' + decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = 'SS utf8 decryptedData: ' + decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

var key = '01234567890123456789012345678901';
var ct = encrypt(key, {test: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'});
var dt = decrypt(key, ct);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="ct"></p>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="dt"></p>
```

---

Note that the posted unit test is unsuitable for testing the code snippet in question, since in the unit test `key` is passed as string and therefore the built-in *key derivation* is used, while in the code snippet `key` is passed as `WordArray` and therefore the key is applied *directly* (s. [*The Cipher Input*](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input)). So the underlying logics are very different.

Also, a static IV is insecure. The (non-secret) IV should be *randomly* generated for *each* encryption and passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext - usually concatenated.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was a great lead in the right direction for me.